# Angular router - use [routerLink] to navigate on component

Tags: angular, routes, uri, angular8

how do I route from `localhost:4200/home` to `localhost:4200/home#app=1111`?

I tried something like:

**home.component.html**

```
 <a class="app-card" [routerLink]="['/HOME']" [queryParams]="{'app':'1111'}">
```

But then nothing happen. And `queryParams` uses `?` instead of `#` for routing.

**home.module.ts**

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  }
]),
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you!

Comment: can you post the routes as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass optional parameters to the `routerLink` as further object:

```
<a class="app-card" [routerLink]="['/HOME', {'app':'1111'}]">
```

In this case the output is: `/HOME;app=1111`

**UPDATED**

To have optional queryParams, you can add the following routes:

```
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
{ path: 'home/:app', component: HomeDetailComponent }
```

So you will have the following matches:

```
/home            matches => path: 'home'
/home/1111       matches => path: 'home/:app'
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
// app-routing.module.ts

RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren:() => import('....').then(m => m.HomeModule),
  }
])
```

If you use child routes, you need to add a further parameter to the path:

```
// home-routing.module.ts

RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: ':app',
    component: HomeComponent,
  }
])
```

And in your template:

```
<a class="app-card" [routerLink]="['/HOME']" [queryParams]="{'app':'1111'}">
```

Comment: Does not work. I get the output `localhost:4200/home;app=1111` but when I click, nothing happen.

Comment: Then probably the issue is with the routes. If you can add them it would be helpful.

Comment: Yes it has to be `#` because it will open the app component with the app which has the id 1111

Comment: Usually you have a URL like: "/home?app=1111" and not "/home#app=1111". QueryParams are quit easy to read in your child/details component and show the specific details view based on the passed ID.

Comment: Thanks, but your update 2 does not help. Still have this `localhost:4200/home;app=1111` as result...

Comment: For the update 2 you must use queryParams and not optional params. I update the answer